# How to preselect a certain section in a newly generated UITableView

Tags: iphone

I have a UITableView that I build up programmatically and want to preselect a certain section header at startup.

Any hints how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by pre-select a section header. If you're looking to ensure that the section you are interested in is visible when your app starts you can use this method on UITableView:

```
- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
              atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition 
                      animated:(BOOL)animated
```

If you want to select a row in a particular section you could use this method (which will also scroll to the selected row):

```
- (void)selectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
                    animated:(BOOL)animated 
              scrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition
```